# how do I change this javascript to trigger on load?

Tags: javascript

trying to get this to trigger when the page loads but it's not displaying anything when the page loads.

http://jsfiddle.net/3GLFA/1/

```
  $( document ).ready( function loadData() {
          var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);
      }
 {
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not use [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)?

Comment: why `{ }` empty block at last?

Comment: Last two curly brackets should be removed

Comment: To be fair, there's nothing wrong with using native XHR even inside a jQuery load wrapper.

Comment: Are you getting an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, what happens?  "my syntax seems to be off" doesn't really describe the problem.

Comment: @David it's just not displaying the text now.

Comment: @rs19: What *does* it do?  Step through the code in your browser's debugger.  Where exactly is it failing?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: @David sorry new to this. here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3GLFA/1/

Comment: @rs19: Check the browser's debugging console.  That jsFiddle code is throwing a glaring error, which is related to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery's `.ready()` method takes an anonymous function as a parameter.

Just remove the name of your function and it will work.

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(document).ready` to `$(document).load`

https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

You use the jQuery method to trigger your code on the DOMReady event. But the inner code is not jQuery.

I think you don't have jQuery in your code. Just add it in your html code :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok thanks. only issue now is the text isn't displaying. added a JS fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3GLFA/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
`but it's not displaying anything when the page loads.`
```

I just checked  that the response from the url is empty that's why nothing is displayed. Check this fiddle which shows in an alert box what the response is.

[`http://jsfiddle.net/3GLFA/259/`](http://jsfiddle.net/3GLFA/259/)

Comment: Please check this example :

http://ctrlq.org/code/20004-google-spreadsheets-json